# Destroying a drive that appears as both `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdb1`

Tags: usb, device-name

My intention is to destroy a Flash drive attached via USB using the command...

`dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX bs=64K`

In the command `sdX` would be substituted. Following execution of this command I would smash the device with a hammer.

The `ls` command was used before and after inserting the device to determine the symbols that are associated with the device.

```
b@hp:~/Desktop$ ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sda6
b@hp:~/Desktop$ ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sda6  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1
```

The Flash drive attached via USB appears as both `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdb1`.  Which symbol is better for my purpose?

Comment: If you want to overwrite the whole drive, write to `/dev/sdb`. But `hdparm --security-erase` is better at overwriting 'everything' (than `dd`).

Comment: @sudodus If you post this as an answer it can be accepted.

Comment: thats right, linux unix file structure is a hierarchy. /dev/sdb is the root of /dev/sdb1  well anyway, there is a nifty program called `shred` part of core utilities. you might check it out.

Comment: @j0h sdb and sdb1 are at the same level in the hierarchy because /dev/sdb and /dev/sdb1 both have 2 slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to overwrite the whole drive, write to `/dev/sdb`.

But `hdparm --security-erase` is better at overwriting 'everything' (than `dd`). There is a useful description in `man hdparm`.

Warning: don't use `hdparm` on drives connected via USB if you want to repair them to be used afterwards, because there are reports of fatal results. But in this case it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this command will corrupt your usb device.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb1 count=10k
```

Unmount it and then mount it back again.

And this will repair your system:

```
fsck /dev/sdb1
fsck -y /dev/sdb1
```

Second option will save your time

Comment: What is the point of repairability? Repairability is a liability.